# Using "Go" or "Go Out"

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, phrasal-verbs

I am looking at the differences:

1. "He went with friends to a concert."
2. "He went ***out*** with friends to a concert."

How are they different?

Answer (score 2):

To me, the difference is:

> He *went* with friends to a concert.
>   He *went* with his sister to the store.

Here the emphasis is on going with friends (or sister).

> He *went out* with friends to a concert.

is OK, but it emphasizes where (in this case the event) they went.
I think *went out* is commonly used for special occasions.
Another example:

> He *went out* with his girlfriend on a date.

Comment: So, "He went out with friends to a concert" is poorly written because "go out" is misused?  So to avoid ambiguity, it should be either "He ***went*** with friends to a concert" or "He ***went out*** with friends to ***attend*** a concert"?

Comment: @meatie I revised my answer so hopefully its more clear. "He *went out* with friends to a concert." is OK, just the emphasis is on the location or event that someone "went out" to. Often its a special occasion of some kind.

Comment: +1 How about "He went **out** with his sister to the **store**."? How is different to the same sentence **without** out to you @user3169?

Comment: I don't think you would use *out* with your sister, unless it was a special occasion. Perhaps "He went *out* to the club with his sister." vs. "He went to the club with his sister." where in the first one the intent was to meet people, vs. just going there.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase *go out* is often used this way to state that someone is going out to enjoy.

> [go out](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/go-out) - *to leave your house and go somewhere, especially to do something enjoyable*

---

An additional but important note that I think is very helpful here. In the **progressive context,** if you use *go out with*, it means having sexual or romantic relationship and spending a lot of time with the partner. On the same page...

> go out with (#4): Greg used to go out with Karla.

Comment: Note that *'He went **out** with a friend to a concert'* does not in any way imply a sexual or romantic relationship with said friends; you need not worry that anyone could mistake you for that.

Comment: ' Maulik V. What do you mean by 'progressive context'?

Answer (score 0):

I think the main difference between two sentences is:

`1- You and your friends went to concert.`

(You just stated that you and your friends went to concert but not very specifically said when.)

`2- You and your friend went out to concert.`

(you're stating that you and your friends were outside of your home to go to concert - more specific)

I'm also learning English, so sorry for my mistakes :)